# What is this type of linking, or direct, called?

Tags: php

So I'm building a website and a user's profile link would be like this

```
domain.com/profile.php?name=john.smith
```

But what is it called for it to be like this instead

```
domain.com/john.smith
```

Normally this would return a 404 error since it's not a file or directory in the root.

Comment: its called url rewriting. you create a rule that translates "/john.smith" into "profile.php?name=john.smith"

Comment: You can rewrite URLs like that with the help of `.htaccess`, Google "htacces url rewrite"

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained